# Object returned is Undefined

Tags: javascript, json, oop

I have an list of Objects and I am trying to dynamically create additional sub objects.  The task works, but I am getting an Undefined result for the parent. It should put my content into the Data creating a sub object. I figure I am missing a step in the process which is something to do with converting a String to an object.

```
var steps_array = 
{
    Step_1:
    {
        Data : ""

    },
    Step_2:
    {
        Data : ""
    },
    Step_3:
    {
        Data : ""
    },
    Step_4:
    {
        Data : ""
    }
}
```

Javascript to load dynamic content

```
steps_array.Step_3[steps_array.Data] = {loc:{location : 4}};
```

Comment: that's not an array. Square brackets `[ ]` define an array, not curly brackets `{ }`

Comment: What do you expect `steps_array.Data` to be?

Comment: `steps_array.Step_3.Data = {loc:{location : 4}};`

Comment: You have created an object, not an array (though technically arrays are objects - but that is outside of the scope of your question). To access vars and methods in an object, use dot notation.

var somedata = steps_array.Step_3.Data

To set use steps_array.Step_3.Data = whatever data you want to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your object is *not* an array - therefore you will be better off using the dot syntax. Considering that, what you want to do is probably:

```
steps_array.Step_3.Data = { loc: { location: 4 } };
```

Comment: steps_array['Step_3'] will work. It's erroneous to say they will _need_ the dot notation.

Comment: Well.. The dot notation worked... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are attempting to access a property which does not exist.

Your object has many keys named Step_#, yet in this code: `steps_array.Step_3[steps_array.Data] = {loc:{location : 4}};` you are attempting to access a `.Data` property, which doesn't exist. So you're trying to access the value of an `undefined` property.